# Datetime->modify('second thursday') not working properly

Tags: php, datetime

I am trying to get the second thursday from a datetime.

### Code

```
 $test = new DateTime('2013-08-02 10:00');
 echo $test->modify('second thursday'.$test->format('H:i'))->format('Y-m-d H:i');
```

The above code returns `2013-08-15 10:00` instead of `2013-08-08 10:00`

But it works correctly when I use the following code

```
 $test = new DateTime('2013-08-02 10:00');
 echo $test->modify('second wednesday'.$test->format('H:i'))->format('Y-m-d H:i');
```

Comment: 'second thursday' is realy 2013-08-15 10:00. but if you want to have 2013-08-08 10:00 as result then you have to use 'next thursday'.

Comment: where the space is missing?

Comment: @shark: first thursday is 2013-08-01 10:00,second thursday is 2013-08-08 10:00 and third thursday is 2013-08-15 10:00, no?

Comment: i think its counting from the date you have provided, 2nd is already passed the first so the second Thursday from the 2nd is 15th IMHO

Comment: @user2659356: yeah your right, my mistake. I have tested the code and all you have to do is change "$test = new DateTime('2013-08-02 10:00');" to this "$test = new DateTime('2013-08-00 10:00');"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First day of month of `2013-August` is `Thursday`.

And there is bug in the code that if if the first day is `Thursday` , first `Thursday` will come in the next week i.e `8-August` and like wise 2nd `second Thursday` will come on `15-August`

this code will help

```
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('second thursday of august 2013'));
```

updated code

```
 $test = new DateTime('2013-08-02 10:00');
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime("second thursday of august 2013")).' '.$test->format('H:i');
```

---

Added By [RC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/180100/rc)

**[From PHP strtotime manual page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)**

> In PHP 5 prior to 5.2.7, requesting a given occurrence of a given
>   weekday in a month where that weekday was the first day of the month
>   would incorrectly add one week to the returned timestamp. This has
>   been corrected in 5.2.7 and later versions.

Comment: what can i do to fix this?

Comment: added reference to the bug. Nice catch

Comment: No, this is expected behavior. `$date->modify('second thursday');` will set `$date` to the second Thursday after the current date. And the second Thursday after `2013-08-02` is `2013-08-15`.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('second thursday of august 2013'));
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one. i have already check and it shows the result you want.

```
$test = new DateTime('2013-08-00 10:00');
echo $test->modify('second thursday'.$test->format('H:i'))->format('Y-m-d H:i');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$test = new DateTime('2013-08-02 10:00');
echo $test->modify('second thursday'.$test->format('H:i'))->format('Y-m-d H:i');
```

'second Thursday' means the second Thursday after the current date. So the expected outcome is `2013-08-15`. If you want the second Thursday of the given month, you could specify it like this:

```
$test = new DateTime('2013-08-02 10:00');
echo $test->modify('second thursday of this month '.$test->format('H:i'))->format('Y-m-d H:i');
```

Note that 'this month' refers to the date currently stored in the DateTime object, not on the date the code is executed.